# extracting different parts of a string in php

Tags: php, string, strip

I have a website that all its stories' title are like this :

```
new job alert from chicago {latest reservation : 3/5/2011}
new job alert from NY {latest reservation : 3/4/2011}
new job alert from LA {latest reservation : 3/3/2011}
```

now in **php** i need to extract latest reservation part

```
$atest_reservation = ?

$story_title_without_reservation_date = ?
```

i tried functions like strstr() or preg_replace() but couldn't succeed to reach my goal

thanks

Comment: explode on { then strip the }

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'new job alert from LA {latest reservation : 3/3/2011}';

preg_match('/^(.*) \{latest reservation : ([^\}]*)\}$/', $str, $matches);

list(,$story_title_without_reservation_date, $latest_reservation) = $matches;

// $story_title_without_reservation_date = "new job alert from LA"
// $latest_reservation = "3/3/2011"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

In order to get the first 16 characters it would be

```
substr ($string , 0, 15 )
```

So try to save all the strings you have in variables or in an array and get whichever part you want with this.

If you have any doubt, comment below please :)

Comment: How do you figure 16 characters? He wants to split the title from the date, not sure how this works as a solution.

Comment: With this, he can get the 15 first characters, it is an example in order to let him find what would be the correct index and length for this.

Comment: IMHO this is not a valid answer, as his str length is unknown and he just wants to split the string he is getting into 2 pieces, one with title, one with date, your answer does not does either of those.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, do this:

```
$entry = "new job alert from chicago {latest reservation : 3/5/2011}"

$string = explode("{", $entry);
echo $string[0]; // new job alert from chicago 
echo $string[1]; // latest reservation : 3/5/2011}
```

Then clean it up however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure which parts you're trying to extract in specific, but the following should work:

`preg_match_all("/new (.*) from (.*) {latest reservation : (.*)}/", $data, $matches)`

That will match the (if I'm reading that correctly) the job alert name, the city, and the date from the alerts.  It'll match all of them, but if you're doing this line by line, you can use a standard `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/sscanf).

```
sscanf(
    $title,
    '%[^{]{latest reservation : %[0-9/]}',
    $story_title_without_reservation_date,
    $latest_reservation
);
```